# In MongoDB, how to make sure all connection will be closed if close() might not get called sometimes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node.js & MongoDB, and I have asynchronous code (`async.queue`) to update MongoDB.

When all the tasks in the queue is finished, I call

```
db.close()   // db is a Mongo client instance
```

hence all connections used by the tasks are closed. However, in rare condition, I found there are open connections that are never closed seen in mongoDB logs. So after a few weeks, there will be hundred of connections never closed.

I researched and found that maybe I should set this option `maxIdleTimeMS`, but this option is not supported by all drivers (node.js driver does not support this option).

Even if I can fine tune my code to make sure there is no such condition that `close()` is not called. I am still wondering what if an app does not call `db.close()` for some reason (or as an extra insurance), is there any way to prevent hanging connections in MongoDB?

Comment: Are you doing `db.close()` on the `drain()` callback?

Comment: @RahatMahbub yes, on the `drain()` callback, but my code relies two `drain()`s, so sometimes I guess the coordination of my code is not done perfectly, so `db.close()` is not called.

Comment: Generally, MongoDB connections are kept because there is a high overhead on establishing new connections. If you have a fixed pool of connections, you will be able to perform your async.queue concurrently and just keep them forever by not doing a `db.close()`. When you call your async.queue function again, only connections from these pool will be reused and no new connections will be created. This way you save new connection time overhead and not have a 100 idle connection after a week.

Comment: @RahatMahbub understood, my question is ... as an extra insurance, is there any way to make sure connections will be closed even if the app forgets to call `db.close()`?

Comment: maxIdleTimeMS is managed on client side. So, no unless your driver supports it.

Comment: Another thing you could do is keep a count of your actions completed and then close the connection based on that.

Comment: On server side you can limit the maximum number of connection using parameter in config file net.maxIncomingConnections, this will not solve your problem but restricts number of open connections

Comment: Why not just call `MongoClient.connect` once during start up and don't even call `db.close()`? That's the typical pattern.

Comment: @JohnnyHK understood, but isn't it weird that if there is no method to make sure there will be no hanging connections due to coding mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

[nodejs mongodb driver drops connection when idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880412/nodejs-mongodb-driver-drops-connection-when-idle)

[Handling MongoDB disconnect/reconnects from Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301725/handling-mongodb-disconnect-reconnects-from-node)

looks like after some time of idle, connection is closed.

It is not clear which driver is used, but in one of that post there is link to docs:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html#server

Set keepAlive to 0, and your connection will be terminated...

Comment: I tried your suggestion by setting 0 to keepAlive, but connections still hangs if I don't close them properly.

Comment: @JoeHuang That is expected. Try with connection timeout. From server's point of view it is hard to tell what client is going to do. Killing connection just like that - is something rude - I think. :)